# Guide not signing the thesis but institute insisting on getting it signed

Tags: research-process, thesis

My M.Sc. Thesis which serves a partial requirement for my honors degree has a page where the guide has to sign to *approve* that the work I did under him is original and it is with his permission that I am submitting it to my institute.

Now, my guide after 4 months of research and the production of the thesis is refusing to provide a digital signature on the thesis and when proposed with the option of the thesis to be couriered to him, rejected it on the grounds of it being not possible for him to do.

I reported this to my mentor and department head at the institute and they are adamant on getting the signature on the thesis as well as the copy of the thesis even though on the institute's demand I got the approvement from the guide through a mail where I copied the mail to the department addresses of the mentors and the department head.

My dilemma is that my department, now, when  I am trying to submit the physical copy of thesis is asking me to get it signed by the guide and my guide works at an institution that is 3000 kms away from where I am currently. I think it's highly unfeasible for me to depart on a 3 day journey to get a signature on a thesis which is legitimately approved by guide already, which I pointed out to the institute already.

**My question to you all here:**

Is there any thing that I can say/write to my department which would convince them to accept the thesis without the signature?
Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why is the courier option unacceptable? Cost or something else?

Comment: @Buffy I gave him the option of covering the cost myself. He didn't clarify why he is not able to receive/send courier but just that he won't do it.

Comment: @Community Please see if it is clear with the edit.

Comment: Do you have email correspondence with your guide where they say they cannot do this? Do they give a *reason* why they cannot use a digital signature? Also are *you* 3000 km away from the institution, or is your advisor?

Comment: Yes I have email correspondence. They didn't give a reason per se for why they can't provide the digital signature. Both, institute and I are 3000 kms away from the guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need an intermediary with the guide, preferably the head of the department. If the head sends the thesis to them with return postage guaranteed then it will be hard for them to refuse. At a minimum the head can extract a real reason for their reluctance.

But just explaining the dilemma to the head might be enough to get some sort of accommodation, though the signature might be an absolute requirement. This might be something that requires a face to face meeting with the head. And you may even need an intermediary (another professor) to reach the head.

Don't, however, send your only copy through the mail. Too many things can go wrong.

Comment: Makes sense, I can persuade the head to talk to the guide.

Comment: +1 for "Don't send your only copy."  That bit me in the days of typewriters.  These days it is much easier to make multiple copies.